# update dom after persistence emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm not using ember-data at least for the moment being. I was wondering how can I update the DOM after I create a new record? for example I add a new company. Here is a simplified version of what I do.

since I am not using ember data this is my adapter:

```
export default Ember.Object.extend({
    findAll: function(){
        return ajax('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/companies?includes=detail')
            .then(function(response){
                return response.data.map(function(c){
                    return {
                        name: c.name,
                        slug: c.slug,
                        address: c.detail.data.address,
                        city: c.detail.data.city,
                        state: c.detail.data.state,
                        country: c.detail.data.country,
                        zip_code: c.detail.data.zip_code,
                        unformatted_phone: c.detail.data.unformatted_phone_number,
                        formatted_phone: c.detail.data.formatted_phone_number,
                        email: c.detail.data.email,
                        showDetails: false
                    }
                });
            });
    }
});
```

The adding and retrieving the companies comes from two different routes. for adding its a modal component which is not the same controller as retrieving the data.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    clearProperties: function(){
        this.setProperties({
            username: "",
            email: "",
            password: ""
        });
    },

    actions:{
        addCompany: function(){
            var self = this;
            var data = self.getProperties('all my properties');

            $.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/company/add-company', data).then(function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });

            self.clearProperties();
        }
    }
});
```

Is there a function I can run that somehow refreshes the DOM? So ember makes a new request to the server and updates the DOM? Or can I manually add a record to the model? and ember will automatically catch it?

I tried doing this after my ajax call:

```
this.get('model').push({
                name: data.name,
                address: data.address,
                city: data.city,
                state: data.state
            });
```

no good.

Comment: As long as you have the template's properties binded to controller properties, there is no necessary to manually update the DOM. Simply, updating properties in controller will be reflected in UI too. Could you please update how does your `model` look like? `this.get('model').setProperties({ .. })` might work I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem here is that you are dealing in POJOs and you should be dealing in `Ember.Object` If you update a POJO, handlebars doesn't recognize this change. If you update an `Ember.Object` called say `object` and you are displaying this in a handlebars template as `{{object.someProp}}`, updating `someProp` will cause a rerender because `Ember.Object` extends the `Observable` mixin and 2-way binding is achieved.

Also, when you are adding items to an `Ember.A`, ie an `Ember.Array`, use `pushObject` not `push` in order to trigger an `update`. I don't use Ember data either, but all of my services return `Ember.Object` or arrays of `Ember.Object` for this very reason.

So create a model object called company in `models/company.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Object.extend({
    name: null,
    slug: null,
    //... all other properties
});
```

and in that `findAll` method:

```
import Company from 'app_name/models/company';
export default Ember.Object.extend({
    findAll: function(){
        return ajax('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/companies?includes=detail')
            .then(function(response){
                return response.data.map(function(c){
                    return Company.create({
                        name: c.name,
                        slug: c.slug,
                        address: c.detail.data.address,
                        city: c.detail.data.city,
                        state: c.detail.data.state,
                        country: c.detail.data.country,
                        zip_code: c.detail.data.zip_code,
                        unformatted_phone: c.detail.data.unformatted_phone_number,
                        formatted_phone: c.detail.data.formatted_phone_number,
                        email: c.detail.data.email,
                        showDetails: false
                    });
                });
            });
    }
});
```

And you can either reassign the model to a new call to `findAll` on resolution of that promise, or:

```
this.get('model').pushObject(Company.create({
    name: data.name,
    address: data.address,
    city: data.city,
    state: data.state
}));
```